# iOS - Validation fails due to code signing in Xcode 4.2 developer preview 6?

Tags: ios, xcode4, code-signing

Not sure what's going on, but with dev preview 6, I get the following warning:
 Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

Now I know you can't/shouldn't submit with dev previews and beta SDKs, however, before dev preview 6 (which is when this happened), it would successfully validate.
I've definitely picked the correct certificate; it's been used for previous version of my app and it won't expire.

Is this just a dev preview "quirk" that will hopefully go away for the proper release? I just want to make sure my update is ready to be submitted on day one of release.

Anyone else come across this?

Comment: Installed Xcode 4.1 and it passes validation... hmm... not sure what to make of this. Anyone else experiencing this in preview 6?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting Xcode and your computer. Delete and reinstall the distribution certificate. Make sure your bundle identifier definitely matches up. If all that fails, try creating a new certificate, that won't kill you. If it still doesn't work, look this up in Google. I remember having this problem and there were a lot of interesting solutions I found.

Comment: Just tried reinstalling the cert. I don't fully get how Xcode stores these things? Even when I delete the cert from the keychain, a distribution profile still shows up in my build settings. Where can I delete all that and just start over again? I hope this is some dev preview thing, cos Xcode as a whole is very unstable.